How to clean all expired cookies from Firefox?
I want to ask how can I clean all expired cookies from Firefox browser while keeping all working/unexpired cookies untouched?
Can this be done by Firefox equivalent of "Expired Cookies Cleaner" (which was made for IE by Astatix software) or by some Firefox extension from addons.mozilla.org?
I want also note to stop closing and removing my questions without reason, becuause I need to help with questions I don't have answer, so can you stop closing my questions? Otherwise I will abandon these forums and go to another.
I tried Cookie Quick manager extension, but it doesn't have option to remove expired cookies only. I also didn't find any third-party software which would help to remove all expired cookies from my Firefox.
